# Error building a package - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I am building an NPM package using react and typescript. But while testing it locally, using npm link, I am getting an error which I am unable to resolve.

```
// Variant.tsx

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export interface VariantProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
    id: string;
}

export const Variant: React.FC<VariantProps> = ({ id, children, ...props }) => {
    const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);
    const recordImpression = () => {
        console.log(`Variant ${id} displayed`);
    };

    const handleClick = () => {
        setClicks(clicks + 1);
        console.log(`Variant ${id} clicked ${clicks + 1} times`);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        recordImpression();
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick} {...props}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};
```

```
// index.ts
import { Variant } from './components/Variant';

export type { VariantProps } from './components/Variant';

export { Variant };
```

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "name": "trackify",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "files": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.4",
  }
}
```

When ever I tried to import Variant in another project after linking it with the package, it gives the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
> export type { VariantProps } from './components/Variant';
| 
| export { Variant };
```

Please suggest a possible fix for this issue.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).